# disabled textarea can not scroll in IE8 - workaround?

Tags: internet-explorer, scroll, textarea

Under IE8, a disabled textarea won't scroll.

For example:

```html
<textarea style="width: 85%; overflow-y: scroll;" rows="2" name="blog[comment]" id="blog_comment" disabled="disabled" cols="30">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere, erat eu ornare eleifend, sapien eros faucibus metus, nec dapibus erat ante sed lorem. Cras tempus maximus eros, ut hendrerit est. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</textarea>
```

It works fine in FireFox, but in IE8, the user can't scroll it, so the user can't see the full comment.

It also works with `readonly`, but I want to use `disabled`.

Is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: It seems that you don't want to have it disabled, you want to have it readonly. Set the readonly attribute and make the background gray with CSS.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,but I just want to set "disabled" attribute and make it scroll in IE8, is there any ideas? or this is impossilbe in IE8 ?

Comment: Setting something disabled is not equivalent to: `readonly` + `color:grey`!