# Disabled Textarea can't be Scroll on Windows Phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have tried adding `overflow: auto;` & `overflow: scroll;` but still no effect on that. Similar question;
[disabled `textarea` can not scroll in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877988/disabled-textarea-can-not-scroll-in-ie8) but no answer to that question. It needs to work in windows phone & `IE9` and `+`. Using `readonly` instead `disabled` is not feasible solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think its something about ideology you set control to be disabled you say, you dont wont to have any events and actions to run from it.